# Can't see Service Reference on server side code (WinForm)

Tags: c#, web-services, remoting

I am working in client/server winform application that is writte in C#.

If I add a Service Reference to the project (that is server side) that my code exists in. I get 'xxx could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

If I do the same thing in a client side project it is fine.

Why can't I access the service reference in the server side code?

Comment: do you have the .dll's copied down properly to the server? have you checked the `bin` directory also in the project what do you have the properties set to in regards to `Copy Local`?

Comment: Not sure what dll's I would need to copy over since I'm just trying to access a server reference.

Comment: Is the reference on the server Gac'd Also check the namespace as well at the project level